# About $142857$: proof that $\;3 \mid 1^n + 4^n + 2^n + 8^n + 5^n + 7^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

Most of you already know the flabbergasting properties of [cyclic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_number). Among these, $142857$ deserves to be the most famous and admired, being (in base $10$) the smallest and the only one without those spoilsport leading zeros. I personally love a couple of elegant features of its digits that aren't often underlined. Their sequence defines a graceful pattern on a calculator's keypad:

[image]

Another (partially related) feature is that they are exactly all the base-$10$ digits that are not divisible by $3$, each one taken once. Yet when you sum them up you get $1+4+2+8+5+7=27=3^3$, obviously divisible by $3$. I went on to discover that more generally

$$
\forall n,\qquad1^n + 4^n + 2^n + 8^n + 5^n + 7^n \equiv 0 \;\pmod 3 .
$$

Even if I'm not familiar with modular arithmetic (in the sense that I never really studied it — I've learned what I know here and there and I try to use it at my best following my instinct) I think I succeeded proving this equivalence. According to Stack Exchange's [encouragement](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) to answer own questions, I'll write my proof as an answer below, asking you to check it, improve it, or replace with a better one (in what case I won't hesitate accepting the new one as best answer). Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
1^n+2^n+4^n+8^n+5^n+7^n
&\equiv& 1+(-1)^n+1+(-1)^n+(-1)^n+1&\pmod3 \\
&\equiv& 3\{1+(-1)^n\}
\end{array}$$

Comment: I guess that the (ininfluent) swap of $2$ and $4$ is just a and oversight, isn't it? Apart that, I love how compact this proof is! Today I've learned to use negative values in modulo congruences!

Comment: @lesath82, Order of suuamnds does not matter, right? You may use $2^n$ in place of $(-1)^n$ as well

Answer (score 4):

I'll look at each addend one at a time.

$1^n$:
$$
1^n \equiv 1 \;\pmod 3
$$

$4^n$:
$$\begin{align}
4 &\equiv 1 &\pmod 3\\
4 \cdot 4 &\equiv 4 \equiv 1 &\pmod 3\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
4^n &\equiv 1 &\pmod3
\end{align}$$

$2^n$:
$$\begin{align}
2 &\equiv 2 &\pmod 3\\
2 \cdot 2&\equiv 4 \equiv 1 &\pmod 3\\
2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 &\equiv 2 &\pmod 3\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
2^n &\equiv \begin{cases}
2 & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
1 & \text{if $n$ is even}
\end{cases} &\pmod3
\end{align}$$
I'd rewrite this in a synthetic way so that in the following I won't need to examine odd and even cases separately: 
$$
2^n \equiv 1+(n\bmod 2) \qquad\pmod 3
$$

$8^n$:
$$\begin{align}
8 &\equiv 2 &\pmod 3\\
8 \cdot 8&\equiv 16 \equiv 1 &\pmod 3\\
8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 &\equiv 8 \equiv 2 &\pmod 3\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
8^n &\equiv \begin{cases}
2 & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
1 & \text{if $n$ is even}
\end{cases} = 1+(n\bmod 2) &\pmod 3\\
\end{align}$$

$5^n$:
$$\begin{align}
5 &\equiv 2 &\pmod 3\\
5 \cdot 5&\equiv 10 \equiv 1 &\pmod 3\\
5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 &\equiv 5 \equiv 2 &\pmod 3\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
5^n &\equiv \begin{cases}
2 & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
1 & \text{if $n$ is even}
\end{cases} = 1+(n\bmod 2) &\pmod 3\\
\end{align}$$

$7^n$:
$$\begin{align}
7 &\equiv 1 &\pmod 3\\
7 \cdot 7 &\equiv 7 \equiv 1 &\pmod 3\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
7^n &\equiv 1 &\pmod3
\end{align}$$

Now I'm ready to sum them up:

$$\begin{align}
1^n + 4^n + 2^n + 8^n + 5^n + 7^n \equiv&\\
\equiv\ 1 + 1 + \left[1+(n\bmod 2)\right] + \left[1+(n\bmod 2)\right] + \left[1+(n\bmod 2)\right] + 1 =&\\
=3+3\cdot\left[1+(n\bmod 2)\right]=&\\
=6+3\cdot(n\bmod 2)\equiv& \ 0 \;\pmod 3\\
\end{align}$$

which is the wanted equivalence.